# injecting javascript references in existing html file

Tags: android, html, webview

I'm trying to inject these two lines:

```
<script src='../../js/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>
<script src='../../js/main.js'></script>
```

in an existing html file, using this code:

```
public static void edit(@NonNull File src, @NonNull File dst, @Nullable Editor editor) throws IOException {
        if (editor == null) {
            try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src)) {
                write(in, dst);
            }
        } else {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(src)))) {
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line).append("\n");
                }
            }
            create(dst);
            try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(dst)) {
                fileWriter.write(editor.edit(sb));
            }
        }
    }
```

The editor that i pass to this functions is actually an anonymous class that has an edit function. It looks like this:

```
public String edit(StringBuilder data) {
                        int closingHeadTagIndex = data.indexOf("</head");
                        if (closingHeadTagIndex > -1) {
                            data.insert(closingHeadTagIndex, SCRIPT_TAGS);
                        }
                        return data.toString();
                    }
```

**The problem/question:**

The output html file contains weird `ï¿½` signs. This is probably an encoding issue but i do not have much knowledge about this. Why is this happening and how can it be fixed, if it can be fixed?

Comment: try `Writer fileWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(dst), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: yeah but the input file is not always UTF-8